# Is it possible to use multiple conditions in parse.com push REST?

Tags: parse-platform

I want to send a REST command (using PHP curl) that will target (for example) the following scenario:

```
where (
(user subscribed channel "channel1" AND user subscribed channel "pref1")
OR
(user subscribed channel "channel2" AND user subscribed channel "pref2")
OR
(user subscribed either ("channel3","channel4") AND user subscribed channel "pref3")
)
```

is it possible to create a payload that will contain complex conditions like the one above in parse REST?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use compound queries with the $or operator. From https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#queries-compound:

> If you want to find objects that match one of several queries, you can
>   use $or operator, with a JSONArray as its value. For instance, if you
>   want to find players with either have a lot of wins or a few wins, you
>   can do:

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: <appID>" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: <restKey>" \
  -G \
  --data-urlencode 'where={"$or":[{"wins":{"$gt":150}},{"wins":{"$lt":5}}]}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Player
```